# Having trouble getting line not to paint during bool condition

Tags: pine-script

I've been racking my brain on this one. Could use a little help. I'd like r1 to paint while the longEntryFilter is false and *not* paint when it's true. I figured I could do this by rendering the highUsePivot na when longEntryFilter is true (as coded below), but that didn't work. I'm open to other methods of it not painting if anyone can think of any?

```
var bool longEntryFilter = na
var bool shortEntryFilter = na

if longEntry
    longEntryFilter := true
    shortEntryFilter := false
else if shortEntry
    longEntryFilter := false
    shortEntryFilter := true

highUsePivot = fixnan(ta.pivothigh(15, 15)[1])
if longEntryFilter
    highUsePivot := na

r1 = plot(highUsePivot, color=ta.change(highUsePivot) ? na : #00bfff81, linewidth=1, offset=-(15 + 1), style=plot.style_circles)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, in your script when `longEntryFilter` is false the plot does not draw, you can check this by making a temporary input `longEntryFilter = input.bool(true, "longEntryFilter")` in place of `var bool longEntryFilter = na`

A standard way of hiding a plot when `longEntryFilter` is **true** would be making plot color conditional like this: `longEntryFilter ? na : #00bfff81`.
In your case it may look like this `color=ta.change(highUsePivot) ? na : (longEntryFilter ? na : #00bfff81)`

Comment: Thank you, I knew I was missing something on the plot itself. Very helpful!